# Erro ao enviar e-mail via produção

Tags: java, email

Estou utilizando `javaxmail` para realizar o envio do e-mail via sistema, porém localmente eu consigo enviar sem problemas o e-mail, mas quando eu coloco no servidor ele me retorna o erro:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Falando que falhou ao autenticar, porém o mesmo código que esta rodando localmente está rodando no servidor, e o usuário e a senha estão corretos. Vou deixar abaixo o código para o envio de e-mail:

```
package Uteis;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class EnviarEmail {

    private Session session;

    public EnviarEmail() {

        ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
        resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dadosEmail", Locale.getDefault());

        final String username = resourceBundle.getString("email");

        final String password = resourceBundle.getString("senha");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });

    }

    public String enviarEmail(DadosUsuarioEmail dados) {

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            // message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(dados.getEmail()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(dados.getEmail()));
            message.setSubject(dados.getSubject());
            message.setText(dados.getMessage());

            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return "";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez sua conta do gmail não esteja permitindo aplicações externas.

Tente o seguinte:

```
1. Fazer o login no gmail
2. Acessar a url https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
3. Pressionar o botão "Continuar" para desbloquear o captcha
```

A partir de agora sua conta está liberada envio de e-mails em outras aplicações.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968716/why-emails-are-not-sending-on-production-server